# Google chart percentage rendered out of the pie

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, dom-events

The data (numbers) in inserted by the user in a form. After pressing the submit button the charts are generated and displayed. The problem is that some of the percentage values are rendered outside the pie and aren't that visible.

The thing is that earlier it was working just fine and I did not modify anything in the .js file that holds the code for the generation of the charts or in the html file. If I hit submit one more time, the graphs are generated correctly.

[image: Charts] 
[image: Charts2]

Comment: is it possible the div elements aren't visible when the chart is drawn initially? seen this before when drawn in a hidden element...

Comment: Yes. That's right. The divs containing the graphs are all inside a table that has the CSS on hidden. The submit button is connected, by the onclick() event, to two JS function, one that generates the graphs and another one that modifies the CSS of the table from hidden to block. The main idea is that earlier it worked perfectly and I did not modify the code since.

Comment: setting a specific size on the chart or ensuring elements are visible before drawing should resolve the issue -- as for _nothing changed_, which version of google charts are you using, `'current'`? maybe try a [previous release](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes) -- sharing the code here would help...